# Newly installed kernel, "unable to mount" USB device

Tags: linux-mint, usb-storage

So I recently built and installed a custom Linux Kernel from the v3.8.8 source code. I had to reinstall the wifi driver and got that working but when I plug in my DiskGo Edge external hard drive I get this popup message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/zermacr0yd/DISKGO: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/zermacr0yd/DISKGO"' exited with non-zero exit status 21: FATAL: Module fuse not found.
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

So how do I fix this? Do I need to install a new USB driver module? Anyone else seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the filesystem on the external disk is NTFS, and that NTFS is not built into the kernel.  (Its been a while, but I don't think it can/should be).   NTFS is normally handled via FUSE which is allows integration between userspace tools and the kernel.

The kernel thus either needs FUSE to be compiled in to it, or you need to load the fuse module (modprobe fuse if you have compiled it as a module), in order to be able to handle NTFS.

For the sake of clarity this problem would appear to be unrelated to USB (its obviously finding the device as /dev/sdc1, and even reading the partition from the error you are getting).

Comment: Sure it can, there's been an in-kernel NTFS driver for ages. It even has experimental write support. `modprobe fuse` is usually executed automatically. In this case, FUSE is simply missing (for the current kernel version).

Comment: Yes there has been an inline NTFS driver for ages - which is generally understood to be buggy, and as far as I'm aware not used by distros.  The preferred (free) option is to use NTFS-3G via FUSE  (Which is a fork of the now deprecated in-kernel NTFS driver)

Comment: It works perfectly fine for reading and is most definitely neither deprecated nor experimental.

Comment: Agree to disagree?  I leave you with this url which I believe shows it is deprecated - http://www.tuxera.com/open-source/release-ntfs-3g-ntfsprogs-2011-4-12/   (If write support is experimental in the in-kernel driver, with known bugs, I consider that to be buggy - unless you purchase the commercial version of ntfs-3g which is a kernel module)